# Selenium unable to quit chromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I am unable to quit the Selenium chrome driver with the command `driver.quit()`

For some reason, it throws a logging error, although, the logger is defined in the `JdkHttpClient.java` class.

```
Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LOG
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient$5.close(JdkHttpClient.java:307) ~[selenium-http-jdk-client-4.10.0.jar:na]
JdkHttpClient.java:307
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.close(Connection.java:190) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]
Connection.java:190
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.quit(ChromiumDriver.java:292) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]
ChromiumDriver.java:29
```

I am running Spring Boot 2.7.14

Relevant dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have an old htttpclient5 dependency due to the issue named here: [Github issue #1019](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/1019)

Anybody knows how could I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: The same issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/1086